# XML to Json Conversion: data order

Tags: java, xml, json

I use a Java application to convert an XML file to json. My xml is exported from an excel table where data is exposed in columns in this order: 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import org.json.XML;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
/*import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;*/

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class XMLConverter {

    public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR=4;
    public static String fileContent="";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader xmlReader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.xml"));
    BufferedWriter jsonFile=new BufferedWriter(newFileWriter("converted.json"));
    String lineContent="";


        while (lineContent !=null){
            lineContent=xmlReader.readLine();
            fileContent+=lineContent;

        }


        try{
            org.json.JSONObject xmlJSONObj=XML.toJSONObject(fileContent);
            String jsonScript = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            jsonFile.write(jsonScript); 
            //System.out.println(jsonScript);

        }catch (JSONException exc){
            System.out.println(exc.toString());
        }



        xmlReader.close();
        jsonFile.close();
    }

}
```

The code runs with no problems, I get a mostly correct converted file, but the data in it is not in the order that it should be: I get something like:
            "2013": 45,
            "2015": 40.61,
            "2014": 42.75,
            "2017": 36.65,
            "2016": 38.58

Also, if I use a file with two tables, the table orders is inverted

Comment: The order of name/value pairs in a JSON object is not deterministic.

Comment: ... and if you need to preserve ordering then you should represent the data as a JSON _array_ rather than a JSON object.